# Is it possible that there exists a non-bijective homomorphism between two isomorphic vector spaces or fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, category-theory

Let's say we have already found a bijective homomorphism between two vector spaces or fields and thus know that they are isomorphic. Is it possible to find a homomorphism between them which is not bijective?

That is, if we find a non-bijective homomorphism between two vector spaces or fields are we allowed to conclude that they are not bijective?

Can a similar statement be made for other algebraic structures?

Comment: what about the zero map

Comment: Not isomorphic $\iff$ $\not\exists$ a bijective homomorphism $\ \ \not\!\!\!\!\iff$ $\exists$ a non-bijective homomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For vector spaces, you can always use the zero map. It is rarely a bijection, even when the two vector spaces are otherwise isomorphic. For fields, here is an explicit counterexample:
$$f : \mathbb{R}(x) \to \mathbb{R}(x), \; P(x) \mapsto P(x^2).$$
Of course $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is isomorphic to itself, but $f$ is not a bijection because it isn't surjective ($x$ is not in the image).

There are some structures where, if you have two isomorphic objects, any morphism between the two is necessarily an isomorphism. For example, principal $G$-bundles over a given space. [There are several examples there.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid#Examples)